# How to add 2 Cognito Pools in AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am creating an app using vue3 and amplify. My app needs to have 2 different user types. I am able to add 1 user type using amplify auth API and that user type is able to register and log in. However, when I do amplify add auth to add a second Cognito pool, I get the result: "Auth has already been added to this project. To update run amplify update auth."

Is there a way to support this either through amplify studio or amplify cli?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to add two user pools. Instead, you can use single user pool and create different groups for different user types inside that user pool.

Could you elaborate more on your user case? If you really need two user pools, there might be also advanced ways to solve your case. For example, using Cognito Federated Identities (identity pools) and adding two user pools as authentication providers.